# What is underscore in Feature importance plot made by pycaret

Tags: scikit-learn, pycaret

Please see the following Feature importance plot that I made using pycaret. On Y axis, I see two Features named with underscores, C362_165 and C359_95. I don't have any column with these names in my pandas dataframe. My columns are simply named as C0, C1, C2..., C399.

What does the underscore followed by a number mean here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edited answer**:

Pycaret creates new features in a few ways. One is one-hot-enconding where non-numeric values are split into features with binary values. These new features have names of the following structure:

```
<original feature name>_<feature value>
```

That would mean that the C362 and C359 values are non-numeric and subject to one-hot-enconding and return features C362_165 and C359_95.

In case of my original answer below feature_interaction (which is no longer available in PyCaret 3.10-rc) would create feature name as:

```
<original feature name>_multiply_<feature value>
```

**Original answer**:

Looks like feature engineering done by pycaret.
Have you specified `feature_interaction=True` in `setup()`?

Comment: No. I did the following:
s = setup(train_dataset, target = 'C400')

Comment: Oh, right. Please check what data types are columns C362 and C359? TheC362 _165 would imply that there's a non-numeric '165' in C362 and one-hot-encoding kicked in.

Comment: This was the case. C362 has either 165 or 0. C359 has either 95 or 91. Thanks for your help.